# How to assign schema/table access to a few people

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-roles

I have a few tracking tables in the SQL Server database which track DDL changes. How do I restrict access to that table so no one has access to that schema and tables.

Would creating a role help? whoever has access to that role can see that schema/tables?

Comment: You can also `GRANT` and `DENY` access to objects on a per-`USER` basis too.

Comment: Have you considered using cryptographically-secure Ledger Tables to secure your DDL change-tracking tables instead of using grant/deny permissions? That way you can let your users see all the changes that have been made so-far (which is essential for people who need to query your database) without the risk of anyone editing history.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a login with the default database and a user in the database linked to this login with the default schema that you want and grant the privileges required by your application.

As an example :

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE LOGIN CNX_foo 
   WITH PASSWORD = 'abracadabra2023!',
        DEFAULT_DATABASE = MyDB;
GO

USE MyDB;
GO

CREATE USER USR_foo
   FROM LOGIN CNX_foo;
GO

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, REFERENCES
   TO USR_foo;
GO


DENY SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::Trace
   TO USR_foo;
```

Comment: The tables should be created using this user USR_foo? and they would only be visible to usr_foo?

Comment: No, if you use USER_foo to create those tables, this user will have all privileges on it. So create your table with the ordinary dbo SQL user.